# Como puedo mandar varios valores en request de checkbox en laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

Genero varios checkbox desde mi bd,

```
@foreach ($roles as $rol)
                                 
                            <tr class="col">
                              <td><div class="form-check-inline">
                                <label class="form-check-label">
                                  <input type="checkbox"  name="rol" class="form-check-input valores2" value="{{$rol->idRol}}" >{{$rol->nombre}}
                                </label>
                              </div></td>
                            </tr>
                           
                            @endforeach
```

pero cuando selecciono varios solo recibo uno, y quisiera hacer un registro nuevo por cada checkbox que selecciono, asi mi controlador. Quisiera hacer un registro por cada check que se seleccione, pero solo obtengo el valor del primer check que selecciono

```
$rol = $request['rol'];
    $user2 =  auth()->user()->id;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($rol); $i ++){
        $useRol = new userRol();
        $useRol->idUser = $user2;
        $useRol->idRol = $rol;
        $useRol->save();
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta, quita las imagenes y agrega tu código, te sugiero que hagas el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0):

tienes que modificar tanto en la vista como en el controlador lo siguiente:

cambiar name="rol" por name="rol[]"

```
@foreach ($roles as $rol)
    <tr class="col">
        <td>
            <div class="form-check-inline">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="rol[]" class="form-check-input valores2"
                        value="{{ $rol->idRol }}">{{ $rol->nombre }}
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

y también tienes que cambiar $rol por $rol[$i]:

```
$rol = $request['rol'];
$user2 =  auth()->user()->id;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($rol); $i++) {
    $useRol = new userRol();
    $useRol->idUser = $user2;
    $useRol->idRol = $rol[$i];
    $useRol->save();
}
```